# SQL-SERVER : Sub query for every row of the outer Select

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

Well i am creating a stored procedure in which i would like the sub-queries to be executed for each row of the outer select.

Every account has some payments and receipts that are stored in the same column.
For each account i would like to produce the sum of this column 
The sub-queries create two columns **PAYMENTS_SUM** and **RECEIPTS_SUM**.The problem is that even if the summaries are produced they are executed only once.After some search i found out that this is the expected behavior.

But how can i produce these sums for each **ACC.ACCOUNTID**

```
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON


SELECT  DiSTINCT

ACC.ACCOUNT,
BM.CCY,
ACC.SEG,     

(SELECT SUM(BM.ADJUSTMENT) AS PAYMENTS_SUM FROM [dbo].[Accounts] ACC   
 LEFT join [dbo].[BalanceMovements] BM ON BM.ACCOUNTID = ACC.ACCOUNTID collate database_default  
 WHERE 
 ACC.Account = ACC.ACCOUNT And
 Month(BM.COB) = MONTH(GETDATE()) 
 AND 
 YEAR(BM.COB) = YEAR(GETDATE())
 AND
 BM.ADJUSTMENT > 0
 )
 AS PAYMENTS_SUM,

(SELECT SUM(BM.ADJUSTMENT) AS PAYMENTS_SUM FROM [dbo].[Accounts] ACC  
 LEFT join [dbo].[BalanceMovements] BM ON BM.ACCOUNTID = ACC.ACCOUNTID collate database_default   
 WHERE 
 ACC.Account = ACC.ACCOUNT AND
 Month(BM.COB) = MONTH(GETDATE()) 
 AND 
 YEAR(BM.COB) = YEAR(GETDATE())
 AND
 BM.ADJUSTMENT < 0
 )
 AS RECEIPTS_SUM,

ACC.SystemAccount,
ACC.ENTITY,
ACC.BusinessGroup
FROM [dbo].[Accounts] ACC  
LEFT join [dbo].[BalanceMovements] BM ON BM.ACCOUNTID = ACC.ACCOUNTID collate database_default  
WHERE     
Month(BM.COB) = MONTH(GETDATE()) 
AND 
YEAR(BM.COB) = YEAR(GETDATE()) 

END
```

[image]

As you can see the result has the same value for each account.

Comment: And can you show us your expected output?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen The desired result would be that the sub query would have ran for every account so the PAYMENTS_SUM and RECEIPTS_SUM would differ for each account.Instead i suppose they were calculated for the entire column the first time and not specifically for each account

Comment: That doesn't answer my question.  Please _show_ us your expected output.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help!

Comment: @GordonLinoff and  TimBiegeleisen  thank you for the response but guys i am sorry but i think that if i could show you the expected result i would have found the solution.Meaning that i do not know what else to say.The sums should be calculated separately for each  account  thus  the sub-queries should be executed for the whole outer select separately

Comment: You need to change your query. It could be that the join condition in your sum logic has a scoping issue.

Comment: @RossBush Didn't mean to bully your question away, nothing wrong with trying to help.  I think the issue is that the OP is trying to do the same thing twice; the subqueries are sort of doing a conditional aggregation, and then the `DISTINCT` in the outer select implies doing a second aggregation.  Well, let's see how long my answer is up before it too gets taken down.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen - No offence taken. You took the time to offer a more performant solution to that of the OP.

Comment: Ideally, what people want are some sample data (ideally as some abridged table definitions and some insert statements, that they can copy and paste into a query window and run for themselves without needing the rest of your table structures) and the expected results (ideally as a tabular representation of those results). They're not expecting you to have a *query* that produces the expected results, but they do expect you to be able to say - given these 10 input rows, I expect (say) 3 rows of output with *these specific values*.

Comment: Saying you cannot give expected results is tantamount to saying "I can't tell you what success looks like", which makes it troublesome for people to be able to *test* their solutions before presenting them.

Answer (score 2):

This answer is a speculation, but hopefully gets closer to what you want.  The idea is that you just want to conditionally aggregate the adjustment amount depending some various conditions.  The other non aggregate columns are pretty much along for the ride, so we can just add them to `GROUP BY` clause.

```
SELECT
    ACC.ACCOUNT,
    BM.CCY,
    ACC.SEG,
    ACC.SystemAccount,
    ACC.ENTITY,
    ACC.BusinessGroup,
    SUM(CASE WHEN BM.ADJUSTMENT > 0 THEN BM.ADJUSTMENT ELSE 0 END) AS PAYMENTS_SUM,
    SUM(CASE WHEN BM.ADJUSTMENT <= 0 THEN BM.ADJUSTMENT ELSE 0 END) AS RECEIPTS_SUM
FROM [dbo].[Accounts] ACC   
LEFT join [dbo].[BalanceMovements] BM
    ON BM.ACCOUNTID = ACC.ACCOUNTID collate database_default
WHERE
    MONTH(BM.COB) = MONTH(GETDATE()) AND YEAR(BM.COB) = YEAR(GETDATE())
GROUP BY
    ACC.ACCOUNT,
    BM.CCY,
    ACC.SEG,
    ACC.SystemAccount,
    ACC.ENTITY,
    ACC.BusinessGroup;
```

Comment: Thanks Tim works great.Also RobbBush in the previous implementation you had right it was a scoping issue